# Wordpress: Infinite Re-direct Loop Error on Custom Theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a set-up a custom theme on my wordpress install. I have been developing with it locally and everything was working fine.

I uploaded to my server tonight and was setting up the fresh wordpress install. I turned on permalinks and all of a sudden my custom category pages are causing infinite re-direct loops.

My .htaccess is writable so I don't think its that problem (I have seen this mentioned a lot online).

The code from one of my custom pages is below - it pulls from a specific category - does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
<?php get_header(); ?> 


<?php
/*
Template Name: Podcasts
*/
?>

<ul class="mcol">

<?php
query_posts("cat=1");

while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <li class="article" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <?php 
                    $imgsrcparam = array(
                    'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( $post-    >post_excerpt )),
                    'title' => trim(strip_tags( $post->post_title )),
                    );
                    $thumbID = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, array(200,200), $imgsrcparam ); ?>
                    <div class="preview"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo "$thumbID"; ?></a><div class="front-titles"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div></div>


                <?php } else {?>
                    <div class="preview"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/default-thumbnail.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a></div>

                <?php } ?>

                <div class="article-over">



                </div>
            </li> <?php ?>
        <?php endwhile;
        //Reset Query
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
        </ul>

        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <h1 id="error"><?php _e("Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn&#8217;t here."); ?></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>

<div class="pagination"><?php previous_posts_link('<< Newer Entries', 0) ?> <?php     next_posts_link('Older Entries >>', 0); ?> </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Anyone any ideas? I'm quite new to this so am unsure as to what the problem might be...

Answer (score 1):

What your doing is weird.

1. query_posts is meant to alter the main loop.
2. You have 2 loops with different syntax on the same page.

The second loop is not doing anything, so remove it, and use `get_posts` or `WP Query` for your custom query.

Comment: Thanks - sorry for it being weird by the way - I am a total n00b in this situation so it's probably riddled with mistakes. I will try what you suggest.

Comment: Just as an aside - my site works fine when I turn permalinks off - its just I need permalinks on.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the above - this was not the issue causing the problem but its good information nonetheless as I can improve my php.

The issue (I think) was that the Wordpress Canonical re-directs were conflicting with the .htaccess redirects. I disabled wordpress canonical redirects and it seems to be working again.